# SwiftUI button not called on UIInputViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am woking on an iOS Custom Keyboard Extension. SwiftUI buttons are showing properly but never gets called!

```
import SwiftUI

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyKeyButtons())
        vc.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(vc.view)
    }
}


struct MyKeyButtons: View {

    let data: [String] = ["A", "B", "C"]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { aData in

                Button(action: {
                    print("button pressed!") // Not working!
                }) {
                    Text(aData).fontWeight(.bold).font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white).padding()
                        .background(Color.purple)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For easier understanding, here is the full: https://github.com/ask2asim/KeyboardTest1

Comment: Works as expected with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Comment: Not working with Xcode 11.3! Thank you for the information.

Comment: Hey

Have you been able to successfully print the text "button pressed!" to the console when clicking on the buttons in the given SwiftUI code?


Facing the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to print either, but the buttons for sure work. You just need to pass a function to the View and call it within the action section of the button:

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyKeyButtons(btnPressed: { 
    self.dismissKeyboard() // dismiss keyboard action to test button press        
}
```

View:

```
struct MyKeyButtons: View {

    let data: [String] = ["A", "B", "C"]
    let btnPressed: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { aData in

                Button(action: {
                    btnPressed()
                }) {
                    Text(aData).fontWeight(.bold).font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.white).padding()
                        .background(Color.purple)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can obviously pass the pressed letter as well:

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyKeyButtons(keyPressed: { letter in
    self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(letter) // append letter to the end of the text input        
}
```

Change in the view:

```
let keyPressed: (_ letter: String) -> Void


Button(action: {
          keyPressed(aData)
       }) {
          Text(aData).fontWeight(.bold).font(.title)
          .foregroundColor(.white).padding()
          .background(Color.blue)
       }
```